# Can´t execute asp-classic scripts in Windows server 2012 when call them from a client in Delphi-7

Tags: server, asp-classic, delphi-7

I have migrated an application that was running on Windows Server 2008 to one on Windows Server 2012.

It is a desktop application that makes many calls to the server's `.asp` scripts, and from them calls are made to stored procedures in SQL Server.

The program that makes the calls from the client computer, is a DLL made in Delphi 7.

This mount was working properly on the computer on Windows Server 2008.

But now I have come to the conclusion that scrips are not executed in `.asp` since I do not receive a response from the server, although I see in the `.log` file they are called and with the correct parameters.

The following lines are from the .log file

```
2018-11-27 15:51:20 nn.nnn.nnn.223 GET /soporte/lnk_mnto.asp COD=MFM0010010LRN&APP=MF&cachedisable=FNFAJDNHFIDLELA 80 - nn.nnn.nnn.nnn HTTP/1.0 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+Synapse) - www.ikutgroup.com 301 0 0 569 205 62
2018-11-27 15:52:36 nn.nnn.nn.223 GET /soporte/lnk_mnto.asp COD=MNF5369168SB7&APP=MN&cachedisable=IHOLGLANIEKMBJE 80 - 89.128.30.175 HTTP/1.0 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+Synapse) - www.ikutgroup.com 301 0 0 569 205 46
```

As you can see, COD and APP are the parameters that the script `lnk_mnto.asp` needs, and the call from the Delphi DLL is registered in the log file, but the DLL doesn't receive an answer.

But, if I call the asp script directly from the browser through this call:

http://xxxxxxxx.com/soporte/lnk_mnto.asp?COD=MNF5369168SB7&APP=MN&cachedisable=HNIKNFNMEJMFBDH

I receive the correct answer.

I know that in the first case, the script is not executed, because I added in the first instructions of it the recording of a line in the database, and this does not occur. Instead, when the script is called from the browser, the row is recorded in the table of the database.

I think it's a problem of permissions, but I have no idea what I should look at to correct it.

Do you have any ideas that allow me to try to solve my problem?

Comment: Is the DLL called from the ASP script? Can you show where the DLL is called in your code? At the moment we do not have enough information to adequately diagnose the problem and provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

No. Is the dll from the Client computer who call to the .asp script in the Server.

But in the end I made a new test program in Delphi, copying the instructions that call the script in .ASP and when I ran it I saw that it returned an error of the type:

<.head><.title>Document Moved<./title><./head>
<.body><.h1>Object Moved<./h1>This document may be found <.a HREF="http://myweb.com/soporte/lnk_mnto?COD=MNF873455SB7&APP=MN&cachedisable=GNDECGBLJBFHBHA">here<./a>

Then I looked for information on the web about this error message and I found the following page that has solved my problem

https://network.convergenceservices.in/forum/68-plesk-panel-hosting/3711-document-moved-or-object-moved-error.html

In short, it says that in the Plesk configuration of the page, you have to put 'none' to the question: 'Preferred domain'.

1. Login into the plesk control Panel
2. Click on Websites & Domains
3. Click on Hosting Settings
4. Select the “None” drop down list box from “Preferred domain”
5. Click on OK

Now my problem is solved.

Thank you very much to all.